# Does "that" have a schwa

Tags: pronunciation

https://youtu.be/htmkbIboG9Q?t=481 claims that "that" has a schwa sound.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/that
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/that_1?q=that

all show it with [ae] instead of the schwa.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/that?s=t

does have a schwa version that is listed as "unstressed" but I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When *that* is functioning as a demonstrative, it is usually pronounced with /æ/. (Example: *I live in that house*.)

When it is a subordinator, it is usually unstressed, and except in very careful speech, is pronounced with a schwa. (Example: *The house that I live in*.)